# 'DonutChart' is not a valid Lavachart object

Tags: php, html, mysql, laravel-5.4

As i am working with laravel 5.4 and installed lavacharts in my laravel folder and now i wanted to fetch data from MySQL database and have to show the same data in DonutChart.

MyController.php

```
class ChartsController extends Controller
{
 function chart(){

    $lava = new Lavacharts; 
    $popularity = $lava->DataTable();

        $popularity2 = $lava->DataTable();


    $popularity ->addStringColumn('status')
                ->addNumberColumn('status')
                ->addRow(['Tickets Close', 5])
                ->addRow(['Tickets Open', 6])
                ->addRow(['Tickets Pending', 3]);


Lava::DonutChart('Popularity', $popularity, ['title'=>'Your Ticket Statistics'
    ]);


return view('chart',compact('lava'));

}
```

}

myView.blade.php

```
<div id="pop-div"></div>
<?= Lava::render('DonutChart', 'Popularity', 'pop-div') ?>
```

When i execute this code, i get an error as

```
ErrorException in Lavacharts.php line 129:
'DonutChart' is not a valid Lavachart object. (View: 
C:\wamp64\www\lavachart\resources\views\myView.blade.php
```

can any help me out from this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer.

The error i was facing in the view. I just changed my view

Here is the solution

From

```
<div id="pop-div"></div>
<?= Lava::render('DonutChart', 'Popularity', 'pop-div') ?>
```

To

```
<div id="pop-div"></div>
<?php Lava::render('DonutChart', 'Popularity', 'pop-div') ?>
```